# SwiftUI Picker inside ScrollView is Not Correct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a master/detail type app in SwiftUI. I want to add a couple of pickers
to the input form for the detail view. The view includes Text, TextField, 
custom TextViews, toggles and more. The view has many more than 10 (sub) views 
so I have several groups.

I believe the only way to get the list view picker instead of the wheel is to wrap
the picker in a Form and to set a frame on the form. One reference is this SO 
entry: stackoverflow.com/questions/57091718/

While this kind of works, I still see a background space that looks like the picker
still has the frame of the wheel view. I can adjust the height to a point where
the bottom space disappears but cannot seem to get the top portion to disappear.

Frame at height of 150
[image: This is the frame at a fixed height of 150]

Frame at height of 60
Any less than a fixed height of 80 and the field is truncated.
[image: frame at height of 60]
Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's the code structure:

```
var body: some View {

    ScrollView {

        Group {...}//top Group

        Group {...}//second Group

        Group {

            Form {

                Picker(selection: self.$selectCoreDataItem, label: Text("Choose Clinic")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.clinics.count) {
                        Text("\(self.clinics[$0].name ?? "Nameless")")
                    }.scaledFont(name: "SFProDisplay", size: 20.0)
                }

            }.frame(width: 380, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.red)

        }//mid Group for pickers

        Group {

            VStack {...}//third Group

    }//scroll
        .modifier(AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard())
        .navigationBarTitle("View and Edit", displayMode: .inline)
        //save the moc

        //lots more stuff
```

Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)

Comment: The top gray area is the section header that is part of a Form. Why don't you just make the whole View a Form instead of having Groups inside a ScrollView?

Comment: Ahh. I had originally wanted some layout structure that didn't look the way I wanted in a Form wrapper - but now that you mention it, that seems to be a really simple solution. And I had not thought about a section header and footer being applied to the picker. I could probably write a ViewModifier to control those too. At any rate, changing ScrollView to Form seems to work for my application.